# LINQ Outer Join Has Duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm running this query in LINQPad. It works except that ProductSeries has duplicate records.

```
var query = from etaRecord in EtaRecord_0140

  join productSeriesRecord in ProductSeries
  on etaRecord.ProductSeriesID equals productSeriesRecord.ProductSeriesID
  into productSeriesGroup
  from productSeries in productSeriesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

  where etaRecord.State == "A"
  select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord, ProductSeriesRecord = productSeries };

query.Dump();
```

I tried using `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `DefaultIfEmpty()`, but I get this error:

> An expression of type 'LINQPad.User.ProductSeries' is not allowed in a
>   subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'.  Type inference failed in
>   the call to 'SelectMany'.

How can I get the `FirstOrDefault()` for ProductSeries so that there is only one row for each EtaRecord?

.NET fiddle is here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kRrold

Comment: left outer join can return duplicates, show what you expecting and what's current output

Comment: The query currently doesn't include duplicates, so I can't show the bad output. The issue is that the data could change and then there would be duplicates in the future. I need to guard against that. I only want one row per etaRecord. And that etaRecord can have a null ProductSeries, or only one ProductSeries, even if there are multiple.

Comment: Added the .NET fiddle link in my post.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect the result of your sample code to be?

Comment: @BobHorn update fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIIHi2

Comment: @EhsanSajjad It shows up correctly in the fiddle, but when I run it against SQL, thousands of SQL statements are generated and the productSeries is always null.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need grouping:

```
var query = from etaRecord in EtaRecord_0140

join productSeriesRecord in ProductSeries
on etaRecord.ProductSeriesID equals productSeriesRecord.ProductSeriesID
into productSeriesGroup
from productSeries in productSeriesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

where etaRecord.State == "A"
group productSeries by new { etaRecord.ProductSeriesId, etaRecord } into g
select new 
       { 
         EtaRecord = g.Key.etaRecord, 
         ProductSeriesRecord = g.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault() 
        };
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIIHi2)

Comment: On your group line, I had to change `productSeriesGroup` to `productSeries`. Now I'm left with this error: `The name 'productSeriesRecord' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: On the group line: `The name 'productSeriesRecord' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: I think this is getting close. Only 20 rows were returned, which isn't right. There is only one record with null and the other 19 have a product series. There should be many rows with a null product series.

Comment: On the last line: `'System.Linq.IGrouping<AnonymousType#1,AnonymousType#2>' does not contain a definition for 'etaRecord' and no extension method 'etaRecord' accepting a first argument of type` Same issue for productSeries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that the collection you are joining on has duplicates? Because if so, you can just group the ProductSeries collection ahead of time.

```
var query = from etaRecord in EtaRecord_0140

join productSeriesRecord in ProductSeries.GroupBy(series => series.ProductSeriesID).Select(seriesGroup => seriesGroup.First())
on etaRecord.ProductSeriesID equals productSeriesRecord.ProductSeriesID
into productSeriesGroup
from productSeries in productSeriesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

where etaRecord.State == "A"
select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord, ProductSeriesRecord = etaRecord };

query.Dump();
```

Now this is assuming that you are working with a static list, not a DB. If it is a DB connection then you should probably do the distinct on the results. It could be done in a similar manner after the fact.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. I just tried your query but now all rows have a null ProductSeriesRecord.

Comment: Ah, and if you remove the DefaultIfEmpty? Sounds like the DefaultIfEmpty is returning the default value for the type, whic his Nothing/Null for reference types

Comment: If I remove the `DefaultIfEmpty()` then I only get rows that have a ProductSeries. I'm missing all the rows that don't.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in a subquery:

```
var query = from etaRecord in EtaRecord_0140
            where etaRecord.State == "A"
            select new 
            { 
                EtaRecord = etaRecord,
                ProductSeriesRecord = 
                  (from productSeriesRecord in ProductSeries
                   where productSeriesRecord.ProductSeriesID == etaRecord.ProductSeriesID
                   select productSeriesRecord).FirstOrDefault()
            };
```

In LINQ to objects this may be an inefficient operation because the subquery is executed for each `etaRecord`, but since the whole statement is translated into SQL the query optimizer will take care of an optimized execution plan.

That's the story for LINQ-to-entities.

LINQ-to-SQL *always* seems to produce n + 1 queries for group joins (which is `join - into`) combined with `FirstOrDefault()`. I've tried several scenarios but I can't get it to generate one query only. The only solution I could find generating one query is:

```
var query = from etaRecord in EtaRecord_0140
            where etaRecord.State == "A"
            from productSeriesRecord in
                     ProductSeries
                        .Where(ps => ps.ProductSeriesID == etaRecord.ProductSeriesID)
                        .Take(1)
                        .DefaultIfEmpt()
            select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord, ProductSeriesRecord = productSeries };
```

So the join syntax is abandoned and in a rather contrived way the first record of `ProductSeries` belonging to a `EtaRecord` is queried.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Not sure if this applies here. I was just adding some notes about performance.

Comment: This seems to return the correct results, but generates thousands of SQL statements, which is what I was trying to fix initially. Instead of taking 1 second to execute, this took 40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your extra `from` clause:

```
from productSeries in productSeriesGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

You should ditch that, and just use:

```
let productSeries = productSeriesGroup.FirstOrDefault()
```

... or just use `productSeriesGroup.FirstOrDefault()` within the `select` clause, like this:

```
var query = from etaRecord in etaRecords            
            join productSeriesRecord in productSeriesRecords
            on etaRecord.ProductSeriesId equals productSeriesRecord.ProductSeriesId
            into productSeriesGroup
            select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord,
                         ProductSeriesRecord = productSeriesGroup.FirstOrDefault() };
```

With either change, the result is now:

```
Snuh 1 - null
Snuh 2 - null
Snuh 3 - null
Snuh 4 - Description A
Snuh 5 - null
Snuh 6 - Description B
```

I assume that's what you wanted.

Comment: The `let` was in the query originally, but it caused thousands of SQL statements to be generated. Let me give your code a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Three issues: all of the product series are null, it took 47 seconds to run (the query in my post takes about one second), and thousands of SQL statements were generated. I wonder if it would be better/easier to just get the duplicates and then remove them?

Comment: @BobHorn: Well that sounds like your join may not be working properly then. (It's fine with your sample, using LINQ to Objects). What happens if you just use a simple inner join? I would handle correctness first, then work out efficiency afterwards. Note that `FirstOrDefault()` may be causing problems due to the lack of ordering... you could try specifying an explicit order on `productSeriesRecords`, and see if it helps. As I say though, I'd sort out the correctness first.

Comment: I was able to get my own query working by adding another `where` clause. Your query and my new query now return the same number of rows. Unfortunately, my new query isn't a general-purpose solution to this problem. Since I now know that the duplicates have a specific value in one of the columns, I was able to add this: `where productSeries == null || productSeries.Laminate == null || productSeries.Laminate != "Unknown"`.

Comment: @BobHorn: Well we still can't tell why my query isn't working - it should be absolutely fine, as far as I can tell. If you change your `select` to `select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord, Count = productSeriesGroup.Count() }` what do you get? Unfortunately while we can't reproduce the problem, it's hard to help.

Comment: If I make the change you just suggested, the query returns in 1 second and the count looks right. And there is only 1 SQL statement generated. If I change it back (to include `productSeriesGroup.FirstOrDefault()`) then it takes 30 seconds and generates many SQL statements. And I understand about not being able to help without reproducing it. Since I got it working with my own business logic, I'm okay now.

Comment: @BobHorn: Do you actually need to whole entity, or just one part of it? Perhaps if you use the `let` clause, you could then use `select new { EtaRecord = etaRecord, productSeriesID = productSeries.ProductSeriesID }` or something similar?

Comment: Unfortunately I need the whole entity, but that would be an interesting experiment. I may be able to try that in a bit.

Comment: It seems a LINQ-to-SQL anomaly to produce n + 1 queries for outer joins combined with `FirstOrDefault()`. I've tried several scenarios but it always happened. Finally I found something that worked, but it doesn't look very intuitive. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an extra filtering step to group by EtaRecord and just select the first record per group

ie

```
query  = (from r in query 
         group r by r.EtaRecord.EtaId into results 
         select results.FirstOrDefault());
```